# chromedp fails to start a new instance of chrome

Tags: go, chrome-devtools-protocol, chromedp

Hey guys I have been trying to automate a task on my browser's machine using [chromedp](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp).

I tried examples on the repo however they always fail:

> unexpected fault address 0x7f7a36461000 fatal error: fault [signal SIGBUS: bus error code=0x2 addr=0x7f7a36461000 pc=0x53a9d5]

Example's source code am running can be found [here](https://github.com/chromedp/examples/blob/master/text/main.go).

As I understand chromedp comes with headless pre-compiled version of chrome. I have browsed the API documentation to see if it possible to pass a port on which the dev tools is listening, no success.

However when I tried [mafredri/cdp](https://github.com/mafredri/cdp) it worked. I came to understand that chromedp is failing to start its embedded chrome. Although, I am not really sure. Why is this happening?

My env:

> Google Chrome 85.0.4183.102
>
> Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
>
> go version go1.13.5 linux/amd64

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, long story short I went to run tests on the chromedp locally installed library through `go test`, it failed. I opened [an issue on the Github repo](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/695). While it was not indicated that it requires Go 1.14+ but it does.

If you encountered this issue, please proceed to first run the tests on the master branch locally installed library. If it is fails with the following log:

> github.com/chromedp/chromedp [github.com/chromedp/chromedp.test]
> ./chromedp_test.go:862:3: t.Cleanup undefined (type *testing.T has no
> field or method Cleanup) ./chromedp_test.go:948:5: t.Cleanup undefined
> (type *testing.T has no field or method Cleanup)
> ./chromedp_test.go:950:5: t.Cleanup undefined (type *testing.T has no
> field or method Cleanup) FAIL github.com/chromedp/chromedp [build
> failed]

You need to know that `t.Cleanup` was added on Go 1.14 (credits to [Oiyoo](https://github.com/Oiyoo)).

I hope this helps you if you are having the same problem.